# Devise: how do I override the set_flash_message method on DeviseController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise with Rails 7 and have changed the behavior of flash messages. Specifically, I maintain a list of them, and then display multiple at once if I need to. Devise's set_flash_message method doesn't do it that way, and just sets flash[:notice] to a message string, which breaks things.

The only thing I need to be able to do is override the set_flash_message method on DeviseController. It seems like the obvious, efficient solution, but I simply can't find a way in. I've spent the last three hours putting different bits of code in different initializers and I always run into a wall.

Is there a known, simple, best-practices solution for this? If it simplifies the question, let's say I just want to add a line to set_flash_message to print the content of the message to the terminal, and I want that to happen every time set_flash_message is called, in any context, without going controller by controller and trying to find every time it's called.

Comment: Can you override it in a subclass?
RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

Comment: Probably, but I'm trying to find a way to do it at the DeviseController level, so that anything that inherits from it uses the same overriden method, and I don't have to duplicate it in every subclass.